# validation rules for student registration system

Tags: validation-rule

Am new to salesforce.
I need to validate age group below 16 years . I tried writing Age__c <16, but its not validating. Kindly help over this.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: what is the data type of Age__c

Comment: Do you want the validation to be that the students have to be at least 16 years old, or that they can't be 16 years old or over?

Comment: @Himanshu data type is Number...

Comment: @karthik welcome to stackexchange .Please try to provide as many as details to help yourself .The question is too broad with less details

Comment: @martin the age limit must be till 16 not more than that...

Comment: At salesforce always you have to write negative way. Like, what should write to occur/get  error.  If you write age>16 years this is positive way it will not give u an error. If you write age<16 then whenever the age age is below 16 then error will occure so this is negative way.

Comment: Can you give us more context of when and where you are doing this? At the moment the question is too broad. Is this a validation rule in the object? Is this some Apex code? If it's the former, follow the advice from @mohammedazarudeen

Answer (score 4):

Just change this

```
Age__c > 16
```

if it true then it will give error.